# Theme error in Magento

Tags: product, catalog, ce-1.9.0.1, rwd

I'm trying to add products to a page. 
I used this code in contents of the page.

```
<p>{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}</p>.
```

And I got this error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a
>   non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml
>   on line 180.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ha. 
I think you stumbled on a bug in the `1.9` theme. .
There is this piece of code in the `product/list.phtml`.

```
<?php
    $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
        $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
        $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
     ?>
     <?php echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This code makes it impossible to use `{{block}}` directives with this template.
You can fix it by creating your own theme that has as parent the `rwd` theme and change the code above to

```
<?php
    if (is_object($this->getChild('name.after'))) { 
        $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
        foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
            $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
            $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
         ?>
         <?php echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yeah, it is magento 1.9, but when I tried to tag that one, this platform told me that I should have 150 credits which I don't have.... Will try your's now.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni. I've re-taged your question.

Comment: Thank you, Marius. 
I edited that phtml file as you told and it is returning one more error. Fatal error: Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml on line 182

Comment: @AjayKulkarni. I've changed a bit the code in the answer. You can try again.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni. If this solved your problem, accept the answer. Don't leave loose ends.

Comment: Okay, Marius....