# Magento 1.9 Fatal Error On Search page?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, rwd-theme, fatal-error

on http://reddottactical.com/

When you search for any product you get one result (not always related to search term) and then:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a
>   non-object in
>   /home/magecenterfi/public_html/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
>   on line 134

I have tried the solution that is the fix for this error on the home page, but it did not work.

In desperate need of assistance on this error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in Magento 1.9. Marius did a good job explaining a fix for it here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/21952/2142

Comment: Followed the instructions on the link to Marius' answer and it is still showing the same error. I had tried that before posting the question. 

I am still relatively new with magento and learning as we go.It is possible I am doing something wrong in the creation of a child theme, but everything looks right.

Comment: @CodyCFC - Are you sure you're editing the app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml file? If that code doesn't work for you, then you can just comment out that code as it actually isn't being used on the latest release of Magento.